# Trigonometric sum related to ellipse

Tags: residue-calculus, trigonometric-series

> How to prove this identity for  $2\le n\in\Bbb N^+, a , b > 0$?
> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{a^2\cos^2\left(\frac kn⋅π\right)+b^2\sin^2\left(\frac kn⋅π\right)}=\frac{n}{ab}⋅\frac{(a+b)^n+(b-a)^n}{(a+b)^n-(b-a)^n}
> $$

First I apply double angle formula
$$\frac1{a^2\cos^2\left(\frac kn⋅π\right)+b^2\sin^2\left(\frac kn⋅π\right)}=\frac1{\frac{a^2-b^2}2\cos(2k\pi/n)+\frac{a^2+b^2}2}$$
Similar to [Finite Series $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{1-\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{n})}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562360)
and [Complex Partial Fraction Decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846658)

---

I get this identity from Riemann sum of [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518173):
\begin{align*}
\int_0^π\frac{\mathrm{{}d}t}{a^2\cos^2t+b^2\sin^2t}&=\lim_{n→∞}\fracπn\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{a^2\cos^2\left(\frac kn⋅π\right)+b^2\sin^2\left(\frac kn⋅π\right)}\\
&=\lim_{n→∞}\fracπ{ab}⋅\frac{(a+b)^n+(b-a)^n}{(a+b)^n-(b-a)^n}\\
&=\fracπ{a b}
\end{align*}
It looks like the sum of gravitational potential from points $(a\cos(\frac kn\cdot\pi),b\sin(\frac kn\cdot\pi))$ on an ellipse.

Comment: No mystery
$$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
$$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

Comment: @NgChungTak You're right. I worked it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ζ=e^{2i\pi/n}$,
the identity is equivalent to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\frac{a^2-b^2}2\frac{\zeta^k+\zeta^{-k}}2+\frac{a^2+b^2}2} =\frac{n}{ab}⋅\frac{(a+b)^n+(b-a)^n}{(a+b)^n-(b-a)^n}$$
Partial fractions,
$$\frac1{\frac{a^2-b^2}2\frac{z+z^{-1}}2+\frac{a^2+b^2}2}=\frac{{b - a}}{{a b \left((a + b) z + a - b\right)}} + \frac{{a + b}}{{a b \left((a - b) z^{-1} + a + b\right)}}
$$
multiply the identity by $ab$, let $z=\zeta^k$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{{b - a}}{{(a + b) z + a - b}} + \frac{{a + b}}{{(a - b) z^{-1}+ a + b}}\right)=n⋅\frac{(a+b)^n+(b-a)^n}{(a+b)^n-(b-a)^n}$$
since $\{z^{-1}:k=0,\dots,n-1\}=\{z:k=0,\dots,n-1\}$, we can replace $z^{-1}$ with $z$ in the second term
$$\tag1\label1\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{{b - a}}{{(a + b) z + a - b}} + \frac{{a + b}}{{(a - b) z+ a + b}}\right)=n⋅\frac{(a+b)^n+(b-a)^n}{(a+b)^n-(b-a)^n}$$
Let $w=\frac1{\frac{a + b}{b - a}z- 1}$
then $(\frac1w+1)^n=(\frac{a + b}{b - a}z)^n=(\frac{a + b}{b - a})^n\implies(1+w)^n-w^n(\frac{a + b}{b - a})^n=0$,

so for $k=0,\dots,n-1$ all $w$ are the roots of the polynomial $f(x)=(1+x)^n-x^n(\frac{a + b}{b - a})^n$

so
$$
(1+x)^n-x^n(\frac{a + b}{b - a})^n=\left(1-(\frac{a + b}{b - a})^n\right)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-w)
$$
equating coefficient of $x^{n-1}$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} w=\frac n{(\frac{a + b}{b - a})^n-1}$$
substitute $w=\frac{{b - a}}{{(a + b) z + a - b}}$
$$\tag2\label2
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{b-a}{(a + b)z+a-b}=\frac n{(\frac{a + b}{b - a})^n-1}$$
replace $a$ with $-a$ and multiply by $-1$
$$\tag3\label3
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{a+b}{(a-b)z+a+b}=\frac n{1-(\frac{-a + b}{a+b})^n}$$
adding \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{b-a}{(a + b)z+a-b}+\frac{a+b}{(a-b)z+a+b}\right)=\frac n{(\frac{a + b}{b - a})^n-1}+\frac n{1-(\frac{-a + b}{a+b})^n}$$
This simplifies to \eqref{1}